# Is there any polynomial that increases and decreases for every integer change in variable?

Tags: sequences-and-series, polynomials

I was looking at **method of differences** to solve a **next in sequence** problem. The method is applicable to sequences that can be expressed as a polynomial.

I started thinking about sequences whose sign of difference changes for every consecutive integer change. 
Something like  `5 4 6 5 7`

Here the difference is -1 then +2. A series like this requires some kind of periodic function but then it will no longer be a polynomial.

If the series cannot be expressed as a polynomial, what kind of method can be used to find the next in sequence for sequences having difference like `-1 +2 +3 -4 | -1 +2 +3 -4 | -1 ..` or `-2 +4 | -2 +4 ..`

Comment: The number of times the polynomial changes slope is limited by the degree of its derivative. A polynomial that changes slope at every integer has to have a derivative of infinite degree. That is, it has to be a power series.

Answer (score 1):

If $p$ is a polynomial such that $p(n+1)-p(n), n=1,2,...$ is alternately positive and negative the $p'$ has  a zero in $(n,n+2)$ for every $n$. Thus $p'$ is a polynomial with infinitely many zeros which means $p'=0$ and $p$ is a constant.